# In Cypress to test getting total number of elements from listbox and then according to the data run in loop and as per each data perform an if

Tags: arrays, for-loop, integration-testing, cypress

In Cyress Test writing an test of react application when I click on a Listbox in the drop down it get list of data.

eg : 123a, 1233, 111c etc suppose have count 50
then select each 1 by 1 however need to compare each that if its certain account perform certain checks

in details:
have searched and clicked the listbox but the issue i am facing how can i find the total number of elements in that listbox and need to traverse each item/value 1 by 1 and when select verify certain asserts.

so 3 challenges where i am stuck
1) How to get total number of elements have tried initial count=cy.get('@alias').length seems not working.

2) after we get how can I iterate through the loop 1 at a time as after selecting 1 item as have to certain assertions.

Thanks
Varun Awasthi

Answer (score 0):

**First**:

`cy.get("alias").length` can never work because of the async structure of cypress. The `get()` returns never the wrapped element but a chainable. Thus you would have to write something like `get(..).then(obj => ...)`

**Second:**

Given this HTML structure:

```
<div>
<div class="item">
        ...many other html code
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        ...many other html code
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        ...many other html code
    </div>
</div>
```

You can get the length ( = the mount of `item` elements) like this:

```
it("test", () => {
    cy.get(".item").should($items => {
        cy.log(`amount: ${$items.length}`)
    })
})
```

**Third:**

Please try something like this:

```
it("test", () => {
    cy.get(".item").each($item => {
        cy.wrap($item).should($e => {
            expect($e.text()).to.eq("test")
        })
    })
})
```

But you must not use cypress commands here. Something like this should also work:

```
cy.get(".item").should($items => { 
    for(var i = 0; i < $items.length; i++) {
        expect($items[i].text()).to.eq(...)
    }
})
```

So you can also work with a combination of cypress commands and jQuery.

Let me know if you need furhter assistance

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this, but to get the count of elements returned I would use something like this:

```
cy.get('.item').its('length')
```

Then, if you want to work with specific elements from that array:

```
.then(size => {
  for(i= 0; i < size: i++) {
    cy.get('.item').eq(size).should('have.value', 'list item')
  }
})
```